# How to receive device/system input in Haskell?

Tags: c, haskell, input, cross-platform

How could I go about writing a Haskell library to provide input functionality similar to that provided by SDL or GLFW? Specifically, how would I go about grabbing device events (e.g. mouse, keyboard, joystick) and system events (e.g. quit, resize, window move, focus).

Comment: That's like asking, "I need to make a speech at a press conference in Latin tomorrow, how could I go about that?" (quoting anonymous here.) You'll need to give a bit more detail on what you need help with.

Comment: Alright, I've clarified the question a bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Make FFI bindings to the primitives provided by the platform (or library) you're building on.
2. Use these primitives to implement higher level abstractions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want something similar to SDL, why not use SDL? There already is a [pretty good SDL wrapper](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/SDL) available which basically has the same API as the C version (but with garbage collection and type-safety).

Comment: I don't want the library dependency of SDL (or GLFW); it adds a lot of unnecessary stuff, and if I want to change paradigms, I have to either add a second windowing library dependency, or switch over all the rest of my code too.

Comment: What you're proposing, reimplementing core aspects of sdl on haskell, is much more work.